# Something trimming hastag from svg href

Tags: svg, icons

I have a sprite with icons. Everything is good when I'm working on localhost. But when I'm uploading files on hosting, something trimming my #plus after .svg.
Only this icon, other icons showing.

```
<span @click="increment">
  <svg class="icon icon-plus">
    <use href="../assets/icons/feather-sprite.svg#plus" />
  </svg>
</span>
```

Comment: By "other icons showing" do you mean other SVGs? Or other hash references (eg. `sprite.svg#something`) are working?

Comment: @PaulLeBeau other hash references. Only this icon has a problem. I don't know why. I can add this hash in browser (developer mode) and the icon is shown.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the `feather-sprite.svg`

Comment: @enxaneta https://1993.kz/ website

Answer (score 0):

Your problem will be because of the way that icon (and many others in that set) are designed.  It looks like this:

```
<symbol id="plus" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
  <line x1="12" y1="5" x2="12" y2="19"></line>
  <line x1="5" y1="12" x2="19" y2="12"></line>
</symbol>
```

The problem is that the icon is designed using simple straight lines.  This is quite unusual for icon libraries.  Normally they use filled shapes.

By default SVG shapes have a black "fill" and no "stroke".  The fill is the area inside a shape, and the stroke is a boundary of a shape.  Straight lines have no inside, so they have no fill to draw.  And if a colour and size are not specified for the stroke, it won't be rendered either.  That's why the icon is not showing up.

To fix that you need to specify a `stroke` and `stroke-width` for the icons that are like this.

```css
.icon {
  width: 100;
}

.icon-plus {
  stroke: blue;
  stroke-width: 4;
}
```

```html
<svg class="icon icon-plus">
  <symbol id="plus" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <line x1="12" y1="5" x2="12" y2="19"></line>
    <line x1="5" y1="12" x2="19" y2="12"></line>
  </symbol>

  <use href="#plus" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you. But I have stroke-width and icon width. 
I think it's my hosting, because everything good when I use icons on localhost